# Error handling didStartUpdatingLocation

Tags: ios, swift

I have created a method that checks whether the authorization is correct, however beside this even though the authorization is correct, this does not mean that it can retrieve the location. I've tried to check this in `didFailWithError`, but it seem to be called twice, which makes it hard to make any kind of error messaging how come is that?

so after i've checked the authorization i call this method:

```
class func turnOn() {
    if (CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled()){
        print("begin updating location")
        self.sharedManager.locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
    }
}
```

and then i call this, which returns the logging twice

```
func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: NSError) {
    print(error)
}
```

Comment: What's the error message then (even if twice)?

Comment: `Error Domain=kCLErrorDomain Code=0 "(null)"`

`Error Domain=kCLErrorDomain Code=0 "(null)"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once check Error Types like this , i wrote in Obj-c but ur question is in Swift

```
- (void)locationManager: (CLLocationManager *)manager didFailWithError: (NSError *)error
{
switch([error code])
{
    case kCLErrorNetwork:
    {


       @"Network Error" message:@"Please check your network connection.";


    }
        break;
    case kCLErrorDenied:{

        @"Enable Location Service" message:@"You have to enable the Location Service to use this App. To enable, please go to Settings⚙->Privacy->Location Services";


    }
        break;
    default:
    {

    }
        break;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you had enabled a location on your simulator.

Press the simulator icon, and go to the top bar of your mac.

[image: Enabling location on simulator]

Comment: yes i know that is the issue, but i want to check for this since this could happen in the application aswell

Comment: This error is only displayed on simulator. 
Running your app on a real device will produce errors with more elaborated messages from CoreLocation.